# Solving Magento ORM race condition

Tags: php, magento

As magento professional services and module developers we need to implement  Magento order processing workflow where order information is loaded, updated and stored from 2 separate concurrent processes (3rd party payment processing notification handler and customer to order assignment handler). Current implementation works fine except that the process is vulnerable to race condition problems.

**Process A:** load()ᴬ -> updateFields1() -> save()ᴬ

**Process B:** load()ᴮ -> updateFields2() -> save()ᴮ

In case load()ᴬ is called after load()ᴮ but before save()ᴮ, one of the processes overwrite the values set by the concurrent process.

Is there a possibility or some common practice provided by the Magento framework to deal with the race conditions like that provided that the fields updated in methods updateField1() and updateField2() are completely different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two options to avoid this race condition. They both have trade-offs.

**Option A:** Make two separate `UPDATE` queries to update these fields, and let your database server handle the locking for you. Zend's DB Framework already has built-in methods for making these sorts of updates. Here's two example functions to get you started:

```
function paymentProcessingUpdate($incrementId, $paymentId) {
    $db = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
    $table = 'sales_flat_order';
    $data = array('payment_id' => $paymentId);
    $where = $db->quoteInto('increment_id = ?', $incrementId);
    $db->update($table, $data, $where);
}

function assignCustomerToOrder($incrementId, $customerId) {
    $db = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
    $table = 'sales_flat_order';
    $data = array('customer_id' => $customerId);
    $where = $db->quoteInto('increment_id = ?', $incrementId);
    $db->update($table, $data, $where);
}
```

Downsides to this approach:

1. If your fields are used in the `sales_flat_order_grid` table, you must update that table too. This is something that Magento's models normally would do for you. You could add a `JOIN` to handle this in a single `UPDATE` query.
2. It bypasses the Magento models, which means that observers like `sales_order_save_commit_after` and `sales_order_save_after` don't get triggered.

Advantages:

1. It's much faster to run a single update than save the entire model.

**Option B:** You can use a locking mechanism like `Mage_Index_Model_Lock`, which is what Magento does while refreshing an index.

**How it works**: Let's assume we're processing order number `100002185`. Process A and B are interchangeable in this example.

1. Process A starts and checks if there is a lock for `automation_order_id_100002185`.
2. Process A does not find a lock, so it sets a lock for `automation_order_id_100002185` and begins doing its work.
3. Process B starts, before process A has completed, and checks for a lock for `automation_order_id_100002185`.
4. Process B finds a lock, so it sleeps for 3 seconds.
5. Process A is still working. Process B checks for a lock again after its 3 second sleep, but process A has not released it yet, so it does another 3 second sleep.
6. Process A finishes doing its work, and releases the lock.
7. Process B checks for a lock again after its 3 second sleep. This time there is no lock, so process B sets a lock, and begins to do its work.
8. Process B finishes its work and releases the lock.

Downsides to this approach:

1. It sacrifices speed. If the fields being updated by each process are different, un-related, and independent, they could be doing their work in parallell.
2. A catastrophic server failure (or reboot) can result in the lock never being released.
3. If the lock is never released, the process may sleep indefinitely, and its work may never get done. This can cause processes to stack up and eventually crash the server, causing a chain reaction for other processes.
4. If the server crashes, and you don't have a queue of some sort to fall back on, your processing may never actually get done. Magento 2 uses [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) to solve this issue, but you could implement a similar mechanism using a database table and cron scripts.